# Calculating Stationary Points of $f(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, maxima-minima, stationary-point

Here's my attempt so far:

$$f_x(x,y)=-2xe^{-(x^2+y^2)}$$
$$f_y(x,y)=-2ye^{-(x^2+y^2)}$$
I tried equating both the partial derivatives to $0$, and the only solution I seem to get is $(x,y)=(0,0)$. Are there any more solutions to this?

For more information, here are the second partial derivatives:
$$f_{xx}(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}(-2+4x^2)$$
$$f_{yy}(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}(-2+4y^2)$$
$$f_{xy}(x,y)=-2ye^{-(x^2+y^2)}(-2+4x^2)$$

Comment: $-2xe^{-x^2+y^2}=0$ if and only if $x=0$. same for $f_y$

Comment: That is a strict global maximum point because $f(x,y)=e^{-(x^2+y^2)}<1=f(0,0)$ for any $(x,y)\not=(0,0)$.

Comment: @Bongo, so am I right to understand that there is no other stationary point except $(x,y)=(0,0)$?

Comment: yes, you are correct, there is no other stationary point

Answer (score 1):

Summarising the discussion in the comments, there is just a single stationary point of $f$ at $f(x,y)=(0,0)$, and that is a global maximum of the function.